# LSTM - How to prepare train from a dataset which contains multiple observations for different events

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, time-series, lstm, preprocessing

I m using LSTM in a project related to MobiFall dataset which contains falls and daily activitives - such as walking, sitting etc - sensed by accelerometer, gyroscope and orientation sensors in x,y,z axes.

So I need to modify LSTM into multi-variate form. How could it be done?

And after this problem is solved, I have to deal with another, there are multiple time-series events in different files which were done by different people. For example, I have got `ADL_1_walking_1_.txt, ADL_1_walking_2.txt, ADL_2_jumping_3.txt` (Naming convention of text files is `ActivityType_SubjectNo_ActivityName_SampleNo.txt`) which contains `acc-x, acc-y,acc-z, gyro-x, gyro-y, gyro-z, ori-x, ori-y, ori-z` data where `acc` means accelerometer, `gyro` means gyroscope and `ori` means orientation.

So how should I train my model? Should I combine all of those files? But doing this will cause model to suppose they are all from the same observation right? So it may lead wrong calculations. Should prepare a training and test test for each file and train the model over and over again? So my question is what are the general solutions for this kind of problem. Can you tell me some of these solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It's just several time-series with same data. You should make preprocessing (if it's neccessary) and can provide as an input just for one RNN layes.
for example

```
model.add(GRU(units=512,return_sequence=True,input_shape=(None,number_of_inputs))
```

Comment: Why is the first parameter of input_shape is None instead of input_shape=(window_size, number_of_features)

Comment: because this is the first layer in the model, Keras needs to know the shape of its input, which is a batch of sequences of arbitrary length (indicated by None)where each observation has a number of input-signals (number_of_inputs).